# RecyclerView - java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception, android-recyclerview

In my app I want to display 2 different viewholder with 2 array list data in adapter .But when run, i get this error.

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
>           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
>           at gjteamcom.doubleteam.CariAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CariAdapter.java:58)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1982)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1826)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1735)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:383)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:321)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1982)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1826)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1735)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)

Here goes my adapter :

```
public class CariAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

Context context;
ArrayList<Cari> cari;
ArrayList<CariP> carip;
public CariAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Cari> p, ArrayList<CariP> pp)
{
    context = c;
    cari = p ;
    carip = pp;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            return new CariViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cv_cari,viewGroup,false));
        case 2:
            return new CariPViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cv_carip,viewGroup,false));

            default:
                return null;
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 0:
            CariViewHolder cariViewHolder = (CariViewHolder) viewHolder;
            cariViewHolder.timnama.setText(cari.get(i).getTim_nama());
            cariViewHolder.timkat.setText(cari.get(i).getTim_kategori());
            Picasso.get().load(cari.get(i).getTim_image()).resize(200,200).into(cariViewHolder.timimg);
            break;

        case 2:
            CariPViewHolder cariPViewHolder = (CariPViewHolder) viewHolder;
            cariPViewHolder.akunanama.setText(carip.get(i).getAkun_nickname());
            cariPViewHolder.akuninterest.setText(carip.get(i).getAkun_interest());
            Picasso.get().load(carip.get(i).getAkun_profilimage()).resize(200,200).into(cariPViewHolder.akunimg);
            break;

            default:

    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % 2 * 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cari.size()+carip.size();

}

class CariViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView timnama,timkat;
    ImageView timimg;
    public CariViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        timnama = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_cvnamacari);
        timkat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_cvkategori);
        timimg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_cvcari);
    }
}

class CariPViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView akunanama,akuninterest;
    ImageView akunimg;
    public CariPViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        akunanama = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_cvpnamacari);
        akuninterest = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_cvpinterest);
        akunimg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_cvpcari);

    }
}}
```

I still don't understand how `getItemCount()` and `getItemViewType()` will work on `BindViewHolder`
how can i fix this error ?

Comment: did your cari and cariP list have same size always ?

Comment: No i think they have different size, because they are the childs from my database(firebase)  and i want to display it to my app with recyclerview

Comment: you need to index your lists properly

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the two arrays have the same size. then you need to get the right position to get data from your array. i here represents the position of your recycler view item but not the position of your array item
here is onBindView Function

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull 
RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 0:
            CariViewHolder cariViewHolder = (CariViewHolder) viewHolder;
            cariViewHolder.timnama.setText(cari.get(i/2).getTim_nama());
            cariViewHolder.timkat.setText(cari.get(i/2).getTim_kategori());
            Picasso.get().load(cari.get(i/2).getTim_image()).resize(200,200).into(cariViewHolder.timimg);
            break;

        case 2:
            CariPViewHolder cariPViewHolder = (CariPViewHolder) viewHolder;
            cariPViewHolder.akunanama.setText(carip.get(i/2).getAkun_nickname());
            cariPViewHolder.akuninterest.setText(carip.get(i/2).getAkun_interest());
            Picasso.get().load(carip.get(i/2).getAkun_profilimage()).resize(200,200).into(cariPViewHolder.akunimg);
            break;

            default:

    }
}
```

Comment: hey, i try to repair at .get(i) in onBindView like your said. but i still got an error . java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3

Answer (score 0):

There are two places where your code is causing problems.

1. There is an implicit assumption that `cari.size() == carip.size()` or `cari.size() = carip.size() + 1`. You may already be knowing this. Just added this to make sure you know about it.
2. In `onBindViewHolder`, you can't use `i`(the position) directly. Consider the case when `cari` has contents C<sub>0</sub>, C<sub>1</sub> and `carip` has contents P<sub>0</sub>.

The positions(`i`s) associated with each item will be: C<sub>0</sub>:0, P<sub>0</sub>:1 and C<sub>1</sub>:2.

You can see the problem now. Here, `carip.size() == 1` which means it's maximum index will be 0. But the position(`i`) used in `onBindViewHolder` will be 1. Which is out of bounds.

You need to replace usages of `i` by `i/2` in `onBindViewHolder`.

That will result in the new association: C<sub>0</sub>:0, P<sub>0</sub>:0 and C<sub>1</sub>:1 which is exactly what you want

Comment: i still got an error IndexOutofBound Excception.
i appreiciate your answer, but i still can't understand how this getitemcount() method work in 2 arraylist sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You have some misunderstand about use different viewTypes. your problem is this function

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cari.size()+carip.size();
}
```

You must have single list item that contain viewType and Model. suggest you to read this [article](https://android.jlelse.eu/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-item-types-dfba3979050) and see how create itemModel

This is hard to explanation on your code but don't be shy to ask question i will answer and helps you